# Mixing text of different format in a single cell using putexcel

Tags: stata

How would you write text of different formatting to the same cell using the `putexcel` command?

For example, I want to write `Estimate*` with the `*` being superscript.

However, I am only able to make either all or nothing of the text formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all I know, there is no option for partial formatting in `putexcel`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to mix formatting if all you need is a character supported by Excel's `CHAR()` function.

For example:

```
putexcel B2 = formula(CHAR(178)), nformat(_@"Some Text"@)
```

The aforementioned command will produce the following output in cell `B2`:

> Some Text<sup>2</sup>

See also [Special Characters in Excel](https://a4accounting.com.au/special-characters-in-excel/).